# Can I have MVC Application Controller classes for AJAX API calls in a APS.NET Core Web Application project?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I created a new .NET Core application project targeting 2.1  By default it uses page routing, so new cshtml files I create follow standard file page routing.

Next I wanted to test making ajax calls from the client to my server. I attempted to add MCV application Controller called TestController and added the following to it:

```
public class TestController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost("Test/RunTest")]
        public ActionResult<string> RunTest()
        {
            return "Got it!";
        }
    }
```

Here is my startup.cs file:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

When I attempt to make a Post via Postman to https://localhost:44313/Test/RunTest , I get a 404 page not found error. 
I think it because my razor project is not routing requests to the controllers in my project, but I am not sure.

What should I do to make ajax request to MVC controllers ?

Comment: Add ajax call in the question. So, we can figure out easily.

Comment: did you try calling your action from postman or any other similar tool?

Comment: Yes I am calling the https://localhost:44313/Test/Runtest end point from postman to try and test it.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute route template on your `Runtest` action doesn't have a prefix specified, so you shouldn't prefix the URL with "/Test/". The AJAX post should go to `https://localhost:44313/RunTest`.

If you want the controller name as part of the route, you can include it in the template:

```
[HttpPost("Test/RunTest")]
```

Or you can specify a prefix for all actions in the controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("Test")]
public class TestController : Controller
```

Comment: I figured that would fix it, but when I add the Test/RunTest attribute, I still get the 404 page not found error. Do I have to configure something in startup to let the routing work ?